# Problem using data from dynamically generated array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, selenium, email, gmail

I have a script that generates X number of random email addresses, then using selenium register to a newsletter on a website and add the generated email to an array. After that it loops on the emails array and checks gmail for emails sent to the generated address and extracts a promotion code from the email body.

My problem is each time i loop on the email array the script cannot find the mails in gmail and i get an error trying to parse. If I hardcode the array it works perfectly. I really don't get it.

Thank you for your help.

Here is the code:

```
###############################################
#################  SETTINGS  ##################
catchall = 'xxxxx.com'
nbCodes = 100
###############################################
###############################################

PATH = "/Users/me/s1/chromedriver"
myURL = "https://www.xxxx.com"

emails = []


############## for loop selenium generating codes ##################

for i in range(nbCodes):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    driver.get(myURL)
    print(driver.title)
    time.sleep(3)

    try:
        
        btn_skip = driver.find_element_by_id("uc-btn-accept-banner")
        actions.move_to_element(btn_skip).click().perform()
        print("cookies clicked")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sys.stderr.write("No button")
        

    #generate random email
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    lt = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))
    myDigits = string.digits
    dg = ''.join(random.choice(myDigits) for i in range(10))
    superEmail = str(lt+dg+'@' + catchall)

    try:
        emailFld = driver.find_element_by_id("email-input")
        emailFld.send_keys(superEmail)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sys.stderr.write("Could not fill the email\n")

        
    time.sleep(0)

    try:   
        radioBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='Vm2aBa RYghuO _7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi FxZV-M JT3_zV _5Yd-hZ pVrzNP RKlRH1']")
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radioBtn)
        print("radio clicked")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sys.stderr.write("No radio button")


    try:   
        subBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='DJxzzA u9KIT8 uEg2FS U_OhzR ZkIJC- Vn-7c- FCIprz heWLCX JIgPn9 LyRfpJ pxpHHp Md_Vex NN8L-8 GTG2H9 MfX1a0 WCjo-q EKabf7 aX2-iv r9BRio  E6Km4r']")
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", subBtn)
        print("subscribe clicked")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sys.stderr.write("No radio button")

    emails.append(superEmail)

    print ('super email: ' + superEmail, type(superEmail))

    time.sleep(5)

    driver.quit()
    
############## end of for loop selenium generating codes ##################

now = datetime.datetime.now() 
fName = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y%H%M%S")

f = open(fName + ".txt", "a")

time.sleep(10)

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
m.login("myemail@gmail.com","mypassword")
m.select('inbox')

print(emails)

#if I hardcode the emails array it works:
# emails = ['rdaiutjrqn9665644499@myCatchall.io', 'sabqasurir0823398987@myCatchall.io']

for nEmail in emails:
    print(nEmail, type(nEmail))

    result, data = m.search(None, 'TO "' + nEmail + '"')# search all email and return uids
    if result == 'OK':
        for num in data[0].split():
            result, data = m.uid('fetch', num, '(RFC822)')
            if result == 'OK':
                email_message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])    # raw email text including headers
                print('From:' + email_message['From'])
                for part in email_message.walk():
                    if part.get_content_type()=="text/plain" or part.get_content_type()=="text/html":
                        message = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                        #print("Message: \n", message.decode())
                        print("==========================================\n")
                        break

    #I get the error on the following line cause no email as been found
    myMessage = message.decode()
    pos1 = myMessage.find('Entrez le code lors du paiement')
    print(pos1)
    myPos = pos1 + len('Entrez le code lors du paiement')
    print(myPos)

    print(myMessage[myPos+5:myPos+15])
    f.write(myMessage[myPos+5:myPos+15])
    f.write('\n')


m.close()
m.logout()
f.close()
```

Comment: did you check the spam box?

Comment: no no, the mail is in the mailbox. The code just doesn't recognise the email address from the array. As mentioned if i hardcode the array of email addresses it works perfectly